# destructors of array placement new

Tags: c++, memory, placement-new

I haven't been able to find an answer for this :

```
T * blockPtr = static_cast<T*>(malloc(nb*sizeof(T)));
new (blockPtr) T[nb];
// use my blockPtr array
// call destructors (?)
free(blockPtr);
```

In that case, what is the correct way to call destructors ? Should I manually loop on every item and call every destructor or is there a specific syntax to do this in one call ?
I know that when calling `delete[]` on a class T, some compilers like MSVC usually have behind the scene a specific "vector destructor" to do this.

Comment: Yes, you should loop manually and call the destructor.

Comment: Welcome to `C++`, where you can stop `malloc` and `free`ing things!

Comment: @Cyber thanks batman #2 , but my question was relating to placement new in general, where I could have gotten the initial memory pointer by any possible way

Comment: @SleuthEye I don't think this is related to placement delete at all, for all intents and purpose I could want to destroy my objects but release memory much later

Comment: @SleuthEye: Not really, no...

Comment: It's "Undefined Behaviour" when performing `delete ptr;` or `delete[] ptr;` and `ptr` does not originate from a `new`-expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should I manually loop on every item and call every destructor

Yes.

> is there a specific syntax to do this in one call ?

No.

---

I hope you *really* need to do this!

Comment: wrap with a template "placementArray"... ops doesn't std::vector already have "emplace_back"?

Comment: @DarioOO: Yeah but that doesn't help you unless you want vector managing the entire block of pre-allocated memory; if that were so, we wouldn't be using this approach in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

When using `placement-new`, you have to call the destructors yourself:

```
void * blockPtr = malloc(nb*sizeof(T));
T * block = new (blockPtr) T[nb];

// use block array ...

// call destructors
for (int i = 0; i < nb; ++i)
    block[i].~T();

free(blockPtr);
```